# Does 3D euclidean space allows vector sum in 2 dimensions?

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, 3d

Is this right to add two orthogonal vectors to to get one vector, using this vector in calculations and after getting results, decomposing result vector to get orthogonal components?
I am a programmer, working on simulation of mobile vehicle on 3D plane. For this purpose i am doing research that whether 3D euclidean space allows 2D vector sum in a plane, so that i can compute vectorial sum of X and Y components, (as car wheels move as this vectorial sum moves, they doesn't move separately in X and Y plane) perform desired computations and again decompose vector to get X and Y components. 
Has 3D euclidean space such flexibility to to apply this approach. IF yes, How? If no.. please guide me why?

Comment: Your question is not clear, as best I can tell. For one thing, orthogonal decomposition of a vector is not unique.

Comment: From what I can parse of your question I think that it will not work because  for any given pair of vectors in R^3 there are infinite orthogonal vectors and two orthogonal unit vectors.  I bet there is a way to preserve direction and proportion in what you're doing but you will need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: I am going to work in SE(3) group, is vector sum approach applicable in this group?